# Как сделать, чтобы класс взаимодействовал только с определенными блоками?

Tags: javascript

Как сделать так, чтобы каждый class *".filter{0-9]"* взаимодействовал с *".filter-block{0-9]"*, а с другими блоками нет?
Код:

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
  if (!$(e.target).closest(".filter").length) {
    $('.filter-block').hide(); 
  }
  e.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).on('click', function(e) {
  if (!$(e.target).closest(".filter2").length) {
    $('.filter-block2').hide(); 
  }
  e.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).on('click', function(e) {
  if (!$(e.target).closest(".filter3").length) {
    $('.filter-block3').hide(); 
  }
  e.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).on('click', function(e) {
  if (!$(e.target).closest(".filter4").length) {
    $('.filter-block4').hide(); 
  }
  e.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).on('click', function(e) {
  if (!$(e.target).closest(".filter5").length) {
    $('.filter-block5').hide(); 
  }
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Может лучше, всё же, написать **правильный код** нежели заниматься, простите, извращением?))

Comment: И почему у первого блока нет цифры?

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос разметку HTML. Вы, кстати, ее можете менять?

Comment: так я понимаю, что это не правельно, по этому и спрашиваю. В вопросе про это писал, что незнаю как этого сделать. Цифра в первом блоке пускай будет 1, только это сути не меняет. мне нужно сократить этот код, только как это правельно реализовать я не знаю, поэтому и задаю вопрос. Этот код я сделал для примера, что бы было понятно что я хочу

Comment: Если вы добавите html разметку и скажите  внятно и чётко чего хотите добиться - то можно найти нормальное решение, а не вот это вот страшилище

Comment: код сюда не входит по количеству символов.

Comment: `<div class="filter">
<a class="filter-link-top" href="#" onclick="$('.filter-block-sort').toggle();return false;"> Сортировать</a>
<ul class="filter-block filter-block-sort" aria-labelledby="filter-block" style="display:none;">

</ul>
</div>` есть вот 5 таких блоков. Нужно чтобы при клике в не блока или по другому блоку они закрывались.

Comment: *"код сюда не входит по количеству символов"* -- так надо добавить всё **в вопрос**... а не в комментарии

Answer (score 0):

Классика

```js
$(document).on('click', '.filter', function() {
    $('.filter').not(this).find('.filter-block').hide();
    $(this).find('.filter-block').show();
});

$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    
    if (!$(e.target).closest('div').hasClass('filter'))
        $('.filter .filter-block').hide();
});
```

```css
.filter {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <div class="filter">
        <a class="filter-link-top" href="#" onclick="$('.filter-block-sort').toggle();return false;"> Сортировать</a> 
        <ul class="filter-block filter-block-sort" aria-labelledby="filter-block"><li>1.1</li><li>1.2</li><li>1.3</li></ul>
    </div>
    <div class="filter">
        <a class="filter-link-top" href="#" onclick="$('.filter-block-sort').toggle();return false;"> Сортировать</a> 
        <ul class="filter-block filter-block-sort" aria-labelledby="filter-block"><li>2.1</li><li>2.2</li><li>2.3</li></ul>
    </div>
    <div class="filter">
        <a class="filter-link-top" href="#" onclick="$('.filter-block-sort').toggle();return false;"> Сортировать</a> 
        <ul class="filter-block filter-block-sort" aria-labelledby="filter-block"><li>3.1</li><li>3.2</li><li>3.3</li></ul>
    </div>
    <div class="filter">
        <a class="filter-link-top" href="#" onclick="$('.filter-block-sort').toggle();return false;"> Сортировать</a> 
        <ul class="filter-block filter-block-sort" aria-labelledby="filter-block"><li>4.1</li><li>4.2</li><li>4.3</li></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```